# Covering interior foam around newly installed windows

Tags: windows, finishing, foam

I had windows installed a while ago and was left with unfinished foam around the edges. Admittedly I've left it for some time, partially because I struggle with the language of the country I live in, but I'm ready to sort it out.

Apologies for my diy ignorance, but what would I *do* to cover this up and eventually paint over it? I don't need deep step by step, just what the products are needed and what the act of covering is called. Then, of course, I have to translate it to Dutch but that's another problem.
Thank you in advance!

[image]
[image]

Comment: In my area of the world, (florida)  covering that would be called "trimming out" the windows. More specifically interior window trim.  The normal material would be some type of wood or PVC moulding.

Comment: Florida is my original neck of the woods: I'm from Georgia, I'm just far away now. Ahh, I see: what I am seeing online is wood or PVC sitting flush against the new window edges. I'm getting good results on "window trim" and "window casing". Thanks for this! Now to translate to Dutch, but at least this is a strong start.

Comment: Ideally, you want Jamb Extensions, although these are normally anchored to the side and tops of the window frame.

Comment: I'd clean up the chipped stucco and just glue some PVC trim (e.g. quarter round) around the perimeter.  PVC > wood because it's more temperature and moisture tolerant.

Comment: Look for something called "platprofiel" or "platstrip". Like this one https://www.houthandelvandeuveren.nl/a-84113630/kunststof-kozijnafwerking/holkamer-platprofiel-30x7mm-wit-600cm/

Comment: This is all very helpful. Thank you both! I think gluing PVC is about my speed and ability.

Comment: @Paul Amazing! Thank you. That's perfect.